# Problem while debugging on VS Code for Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

I have uninstalled **Android Studio** yesterday without erasing the SDK file and the emulator so now when I try to run `flutter doctor` in the command line it logs this :-

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Omar>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed
      instructions.
[!] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    X Unable to determine bundled Java version.
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.44.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

C:\Users\Omar>
```

- So how can I solve these issues to run normally from VS Code and
  without installing the Android Studio ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Flutter's [install guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows):

> **Note:** Flutter relies on a full installation of Android Studio to supply its Android platform dependencies. However, you can write your Flutter apps in a number of editors.